# Apache POI - maximum number of conditional formatting per one sheet

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

Does anyone know, if there is one, what is the maximium number of conditional formatting rules per one sheet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The number of conditional formats per cell is limited to 3 for the older .xls binary format, in the newer .xlsx format it is unlimited, see class `SpreadsheetVersion` at https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html.

Apart from that Apache POI does not know about any limitation related to conditional formatting currently, although Excel might apply one, so your best bet is to do a quick test with the maximum number that you will need to see if Excel can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

From the following error:

[image]

it seems that the maximum number of styles you can have in a .xlsx Workbook is 64000.